# Calculating $[7](t)$ polynomial of elliptic curve with computer

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, computational-mathematics, sagemath

Let $E:y^2=x^3+x/\Bbb{Q}_7(\sqrt{-1})$ be an elliptic curve. Let $ \hat E$ be a formal group of $E$.
I want to prove $[7](t)≡t^{49}mod7\Bbb{Z}_7$ does not hold, so indeed I want to know the coeffients of $t^{49},t^{50},t^{51},・・,$ but this is impossible with hand calculation.
But I'm not familiar with computer calculating. I want to be able to use computer, but result only is ok here, thank you for your help.

Comment: It is a formal series, infinitely many coefficients, so what do you mean with calculate? What you can do is to compute the rational map $(x,y)\mapsto [7](x,y)=(f_7(x,y),g_7(x,y))$ then expand $g_7/f_7$ at $\infty$ as a formal series in $x/y$, you'll get a recurrence formula for the coefficients.

Comment: Sorry, previous question was ambiguous. Indeed, The series starts from $t^{49}$ with mod$7$ reduction because it is super singular, I want to calculate the term beyond the term beyond $t^{49}$, so for example, I want to know coefficients of $t^{49},t^{50},・・・$

Comment: The curve is indeed supersingular at $p=7$, so that the formal expansion of $[p]$ is zero till the $p^2$-th degree, in this case $49$. But it’s a formal-group fact that now, $[p](x)=g(x^{p^2})$, so the next possible nonzero coefficient in $[7]$ will be in degree $98$.

Comment: Whoops! I should delete the above, not because there’s anything wrong with it, but because it misses the point seriously. You should expect of a supersingular elliptic curve over $\Bbb F_p$ that $[-p]$ is the square of Frobenius; here, $[7](X,Y)=(X^{49},-Y^{49})$. The formal expansion of $[7](x)$ then should be $-x^{49}$,  a *polynomial*.

Comment: Thank you very much. Because $ \hat{E}$ is Lubin Tate  formal group law with respect to a prime which is an image of grossencharacter, thus $[ \sqrt{-7}](t)≡t^{7}mod7\Bbb{Z}_7$ holds. So without computer calculation, we can conclude $[ 7](t)≡-t^{49}$, Do I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working over $\Bbb F_7$, the field with seven elements, sage gives:

```
sage: EllipticCurve(GF(7), [1, 0]).formal_group().mult_by_n(7, 344)
6*t^49 + O(t^344)
```

Over $\Bbb Q$ the result is not so simply displayed, i will adjust manually:

```
sage: EllipticCurve(QQ, [1, 0]).formal_group().mult_by_n(7, 63)
7*t - 6720*t^5 + 5367040*t^9 - 4353090560*t^13 + 3530994503680*t^17 
    - 2864078396211200*t^21
    + 2323127369478766592*t^25
    - 1884348184548019011584*t^29
    + 1528443132789675420286976*t^33 
    - 1239759418841491638287597568*t^37
    + 1005600655750474908385232814080*t^41
    - 815668478478403789879107278340096*t^45
    + 661609619065682693232195492602970112*t^49
    - 536648527667515381010030082244189618176*t^53 
    + 435289382059484601080905836042899144310784*t^57
    - 353074379906097040686068218826179876382310400*t^61 + O(t^63)
```

And indeed, the coefficient in $t^{49}$ is $-1$ modulo seven:

```
sage: 661609619065682693232195492602970112 % 7
6
```

---

*Later comment:*
One can reproduce the same also in pari/gp.
See also:

[MO related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366818/reference-for-the-3-series-of-an-elliptic-formal-group-law)

Code:

```
{ E = ellinit([0, 0, 0, 1, 0]); 
  prec = 70; 
  f = subst(ellformalexp(E, prec), x, 7*ellformallog(E, prec));
  }
```

And after copy+paste into the pari interpreter:

```
? f
%13 = 7*x - 6720*x^5 + 5367040*x^9 - 4353090560*x^13 + 3530994503680*x^17
          - 2864078396211200*x^21
          + 2323127369478766592*x^25
          - 1884348184548019011584*x^29
          + 1528443132789675420286976*x^33
          - 1239759418841491638287597568*x^37
          + 1005600655750474908385232814080*x^41
          - 815668478478403789879107278340096*x^45
          + 661609619065682693232195492602970112*x^49
          - 536648527667515381010030082244189618176*x^53
          + 435289382059484601080905836042899144310784*x^57
          - 353074379906097040686068218826179876382310400*x^61
          + 286387683421690457469675756519873962955287560192*x^65
          - 232296393857452115655956549775515957596755312246784*x^69 + O(x^71)
```

And pari gives the result almost instantly. (In sage we may need some coffee in between, and there is no problem if we have to buy it first next corner.)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the answer I was looking for. Can we calculate by PARI GP in the same way ? Or it can be done only by sage math ?